# Precompiled CSS File not found with rails 4 asset pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, asset-pipeline, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm starting in rails and I've got an application that is working in dev (webrick).

The problem is: the precompiled CSS file is not found in production.

Now I host it on heroku and deploy it. I have a message saying that assets are precompiled (so it's not a compilation error) and everything is by-default for settings.

I've ls the /public/assets folder and everything is in there. I can even `cat` the application-*.css file and I get the full content I should have.

Now when I try to access the CSS file it gives me an error 404 (even tho it's an auto-generated css link using `<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all" %>`). So definetly it's not a problem that I did hardcode the CSS link.

I'm not exactly sure on what would be the next check to perform.

If you're curious on the output, it is currently publicly accessible [here](http://onfaitquoi-dev.herokuapp.com).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try changing the configuration option `config.serve_static_assets = false` to `config.serve_static_assets = true` in your `config/environments/production.rb` if you haven't already done that.

Comment: Well that seemed to do the trick. Now I just need to figure out for images.

Comment: @Erick, images should be taken care by that configuration too.  Do you see the images in the `public/assets/` directory?  By the way how are you referencing these images, is it using `image_path` helper?

Comment: i must admet I reference them in hardcoded way via /assets/something.jpg. I will try to use the image_path helper and see then.

Comment: @Erick, yes please proceed.  That should take care of the image issue.

Comment: Works perfectly with the sass mixin image-url. Thanks!

Comment: Rails 4.2 has  `config.serve_static_files = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?`
- for heroku I just needed `heroku config:set RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES=true` to make it work

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that fixed it for me in Rails 4 was

```
config.assets.compile = true
```

in `config/environments/production.rb`

This would fall back to the assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed, according to the documentation.

Comment: The docs also highly recommend never setting this to true in production just to make the app work ><

Comment: @bkunzi01 theoretically, the documentation is right. In practice, though, this will be compiled only once so I can take that risk =)

Comment: Cool how do you force it to compile only once after deploy?  My apps performance get crushed when I allow this :(